# Balance inuqiry using the Visa Developer API

Tags: python, api, credit-card

Ignoring PCI Compliance for now, could someone lead me to some documentation or example code oh how to pull my end users credit card balance and credit card debt that needs paying off(Visa).
Im just experimenting a bit, wanted to make a simple interface to pull this information.
Thanks